# How should I connect a power inlet box for a portable generator?

Tags: generator

How to wire Generator Inlet Power box 50 amps in Main Panel? There is no Ground busbar in the Main Panel, only Neutral busbar bonded to the Ground which has mixed connection of Neutral & Ground wires.

Comment: Welcome. Please revise your post to provide much more detail. No one can give you good answers with such vague information.

Comment: How about a picture of your panel. Are you referring to the transfer switch to the main panel?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of your main panel please?  Also, what make and model of generator are you planning to use?

Answer (score 2):

### You MUST install a proper *interlock*

This is a sliding plate type device that positively prevents the generator breaker and the utility main breaker from being turned on at the same time.  This can be tricky on some panels, including very old panels and "Rule of Six" (multiple main breaker) panels.  We can help.

Also, the generator breaker must have a strap-down/tie-down so it can't come off simply by rocking out.

### Then, install neutral and ground as you find them

Since you find them both on the same bar, you can put them on the same bar.  This is because it is a *main panel*, and the bars would be bonded together *anyway* even if they were separate.

Comment: Perhaps note that depending on the configuration of the main panel - e.g., if it has a separate main breaker at the top - then some significant reconfiguration may be needed, which may not even be *possible* if the panel is full and/or depending on other limitations.